# Spring Actuator JVM metrics not showing when GlobalMethodSecurity is enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I'm setting up Spring Actuator in an existing Spring Boot application. Everything works fine, except that JVM metrics (CPU, memory, GC, ..) are missing from the one returned by `/metrics` endpoint.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.4. I explicitly configured `GlobalMethodSecurity` and exluded `SecurityAutoConfiguration`.

This is my security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    private final IAuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public MethodSecurityConfig(IAuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(authService);
    }
}
```

While these are the metrics properties that I'm using:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  server:
    address: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8080
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure.include: metrics,prometheus
      exposure.exclude:
  metrics:
    enable.jvm: true
```

With this configuration, available metrics are:

```
{
  "names": [
    "jdbc.connections.active",
    "jdbc.connections.max",
    "jdbc.connections.min",
    "tomcat.global.sent",
    "tomcat.sessions.created",
    "tomcat.global.request.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.idle",
    "hikaricp.connections.pending",
    "tomcat.global.request",
    "tomcat.sessions.expired",
    "hikaricp.connections",
    "tomcat.global.received",
    "hikaricp.connections.active",
    "hikaricp.connections.creation",
    "tomcat.sessions.rejected",
    "tomcat.threads.config.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.min",
    "tomcat.global.error",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
    "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.usage",
    "tomcat.threads.current",
    "hikaricp.connections.timeout",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.acquire",
    "tomcat.threads.busy"
  ]
}
```

If I temporarly remove `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`, the available metrics become:

```
{
  "names": [
    "jvm.threads.states",
    "jdbc.connections.active",
    "process.files.max",
    "jvm.memory.used",
    "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
    "jvm.memory.max",
    "system.load.average.1m",
    "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
    "jdbc.connections.max",
    "jdbc.connections.min",
    "jvm.memory.committed",
    "system.cpu.count",
    "tomcat.global.sent",
    "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
    "tomcat.sessions.created",
    "jvm.threads.daemon",
    "system.cpu.usage",
    "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
    "tomcat.global.request.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.idle",
    "hikaricp.connections.pending",
    "tomcat.global.request",
    "tomcat.sessions.expired",
    "hikaricp.connections",
    "jvm.threads.live",
    "jvm.threads.peak",
    "tomcat.global.received",
    "hikaricp.connections.active",
    "hikaricp.connections.creation",
    "process.uptime",
    "tomcat.sessions.rejected",
    "process.cpu.usage",
    "tomcat.threads.config.max",
    "jvm.classes.loaded",
    "hikaricp.connections.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.min",
    "jvm.classes.unloaded",
    "tomcat.global.error",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
    "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
    "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
    "log4j2.events",
    "hikaricp.connections.usage",
    "tomcat.threads.current",
    "jvm.gc.pause",
    "hikaricp.connections.timeout",
    "process.files.open",
    "jvm.buffer.count",
    "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.acquire",
    "tomcat.threads.busy",
    "process.start.time"
  ]
}
```

I expect that the security of the method should not affect the publication of JVM metrics. 
How should I configure Actuator/Security in order to have all metrics?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I managed to make it work by adding this configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class ActuatorMetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    InitializingBean forcePrometheusPostProcessor(BeanPostProcessor meterRegistryPostProcessor, PrometheusMeterRegistry registry) {
        return () -> meterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(registry, "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day, I've a complex setup of different libraries being included each one using the MeterRegistry, and I've spent over one hour trying many different things after the jvm metrics stopped being exposed following what I thought was a small change.

Comment: Worked for me as well so I filed a report in the hope that this will get fixed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26684

Comment: In the issue on github, it said that it was fixed since 2.5.1 but I have the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set` if I upgrade to 2.5.1, do you have any idea please?

Comment: Worked for me as well however when I run my automation tests, I get the beanNotFoundException for prometheusRegistry

Comment: thanks! Solved the problem